# Android sdk manager can't download packages

Tags: android, sdk

PLEASE I want a download link for:

SDK Platform android 6 API 23 rev 2.zip

I can't download it from inside sdk manager because my internet connection isn't stable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go here https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-12.xml

Find the sdk version you want. In your case `<sdk:api-level>23</sdk:api-level>`

Replace repositry-12.xml in the url from the first step with the `<sdk:url>`.In your case `android-23_r02.zip`.

So https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-23_r02.zip should get what you want.